# why does it not work: find least amount of swaps needed to make either/both array A or B uniform if possible?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
Given arrays:

A = [1,2,2,2];
B = [2,3,4,5];
```

The answer would be 1. Swap at index 0.

If not possible for none of them to be uniform then return -1.

My approach is to compare every element in both arrays with item at 0 index of that array. If it doesn't match see if element at 0 is in other array at same index. If not then answer is -1, as no amount of swaps can result in 100% uniform array.

This question can be found on leetcode, I'm practicing and at my wits end.
https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-domino-rotations-for-equal-row/submissions/

```
function minDominoRotations(A, B) {
    let aCount = 0;
    let bCount = 0;
    let allA = true;
    let allB = true;

    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] !== A[0]) {
            if (B[i] === A[0]) {
                aCount++;
            } else {
                allA = false;
            }
        }

        if (B[i] !== B[0]) {
            if (A[i] === B[0]) {
                bCount++;
            } else {
                allB = false;
            }
        } 
    }

    if (allA || allB) {
        if (allA && allB) {
            return Math.min(aCount, bCount);
        } else if (allA) {
            return aCount;
        } else {
            return bCount;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

};
```

Comment: both are 1. that's what they should be visually looking at them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make each element of first row to A[0] or each element of second row to B[0].

But each element of first row can be made to B[0] or each element of second row can be made to A[0].

For example:

> A = [1,2,2,2];
>    B = [2,3,4,5];

In this case, in your code allA will be false and bCount will be 3, so answer will be 3.

But if you swap A[0] and B[0], the answer will be 1.

So consider the case of equality of all A[i]  to B[0] and as well as the case of equality of all B[i] to A[0].

I have changed your code to get desired result. 
My accepted code is :

```
function minDominoRotations(A, B) {
    let aCount = 0;
    let bCount = 0;
    let allA = true;
    let allB = true;
    let res=A.length+1;

    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] !== A[0]) {
            if (B[i] === A[0]) {
                aCount++;
            } else {
                allA = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(allA)res=Math.min(res,aCount);

    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (B[i] !== B[0]) {
            if (A[i] === B[0]) {
                bCount++;
            } else {
                allB = false;
            }
        } 
    }
       if(allB)res=Math.min(res,bCount);
   allA=true,allB=true;
   aCount=0,bCount=0;
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] !== B[0]) {
            if (B[i] === B[0]) {
                aCount++;
            } else {
                allA = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(allA)res=Math.min(res,aCount);

    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (B[i] !== A[0]) {
            if (A[i] === A[0]) {
                bCount++;
            } else {
                allB = false;
            }
        } 
    }
       if(allB)res=Math.min(res,bCount);
    if (res<A.length) {
       return res;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

};
```

Comment: nice catch, i see the problem. ill try fixing it

Comment: @MuhammadUmer If my comment is helpful, the click it as helpful. Thanks :D

Comment: i cant solve it, do you have any idea what could be solution.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I changed your code and added in my comment. I also get accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int minDominoRotations(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int min = Math.min(swaps(A[0], A, B), swaps(B[0], A, B));
        min = Math.min(min, Math.min(swaps(A[0], B, A), swaps(B[0], B, A)));
        return min == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : min;
    }
    
    int swaps(int t, int[] A, int[] B) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] != t) {
                if (B[i] == t) result++;s
                else return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```